# mysql order by collation

Tags: mysql, sorting, collate

I want to sort the results of MySQL based on the best match by using collate

> query => zeķ

want to show

```
Vīriešu zeķes
Sieviešu zeķes
Daivinga zeķes
.
.
.
Mācību līdzekļi
```

I mean show all characters match (zek, ZEK, zeķ, etc) but sort by character user entered (zeķ)

I did tests:
BINARY in order by => no success

used ( order by `name` LIKE 'zeķ' collate utf8mb4_general_ci) different colloate => no success

I get

```
1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_cs'
```

for xxx_unicode_cs & xxx__unicode_bin
can't change the setting of MySQL on the server (don't have access, host will not do it)

MySQL version is 5.7

result of `SHOW CHARACTER SET`

getting this result

```
big5_chinese_ci
dec8_swedish_ci
cp850_general_ci
hp8_english_ci
koi8r_general_ci
latin1_swedish_ci
latin2_general_ci
swe7_swedish_ci
ascii_general_ci
ujis_japanese_ci
sjis_japanese_ci
hebrew_general_ci
tis620_thai_ci
euckr_korean_ci
koi8u_general_ci
gb2312_chinese_ci
greek_general_ci
cp1250_general_ci
gbk_chinese_ci
latin5_turkish_ci
armscii8_general_ci
utf8_general_ci
ucs2_general_ci
cp866_general_ci
keybcs2_general_ci
macce_general_ci
macroman_general_ci
cp852_general_ci
latin7_general_ci
utf8mb4_general_ci
cp1251_general_ci
utf16_general_ci
utf16le_general_ci
cp1256_general_ci
cp1257_general_ci
utf32_general_ci
binary
geostd8_general_ci
cp932_japanese_ci
eucjpms_japanese_ci
```

using UNION made my query very slow, but result was fine

Comment: ```ORDER BY LOCATE('zeķ', column) DESC, column```

Comment: that is interesting, it worked for this case, checking in other possible situations, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**show all characters match (zek, ZEK, zeķ, etc)**

`LIKE` is anchored at both ends, hence `LIKE 'zeķ'` is the same as `= 'zeķ'`; instead do any of these

```
LIKE '%zeķ%'
LIKE '%zek%'
LIKE '%ZEK%'
(etc)
```

with a suitable `_ci` collation (for "Case Insensitive").  Note that in all utf8/utf8mb4 `utf8%ci` collations (except latvian), K=k=Ķ=ķ .  Ref: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html .  For utf8mb4_latvian_ci, k-cedilla is treated as a letter between "K" an "L"

**but sort by character user entered (zeķ)**

This gets trickier.

```
ORDER BY col LIKE '%zeķ' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DESC,
         ((anything else to sort by))
```

That forces an exact match for accents/caps, which turns into `0` (first) for an exact match.  The second part of the `ORDER BY` is optional; it could be some other thing to sort by (eg date or the complete column).

**Preferred collation for 5.7**

utf8_unicode_520_ci / utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

For 8.0:  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

**Notes**

- Most of my answer works equally well for "utf8", "utf8mb3", or "utf8mb4" with suitable name changes in `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`/`COLLATE`,
- The first part of a `COLLATION` name matches the `CHARACTER SET` name.
- `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` refer to Case Insensitive and either Accent Insensitive or Sensitive.

Comment: regarding "ORDER BY col LIKE '%zeķ' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin" I don't know what user types, maybe he types zeķes so I need to check with '%zeķes%' 
unfortunately, the cs and bin collation are not supported by the hosting that we have, they don't change the MySQL setting also

Comment: @ArashRabiee - _bin should always be available (including 5.7); show should the `ORDER BY ... COLLATE ...` syntax.  `_cs` is not available in 5.7.  `LIKE "%zekes%"` will never match `"zek"`; were you trying that?